# What's the reason to have width and value-now in Bootstrap 4 progress-bar?

Tags: html, progress-bar, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" 

   aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" 
   aria-valuemax="100">
</div>
</div>
```

The first div is a standard container from HTML. The 2nd div's "progress-bar" is from bootstrap.

But the 2nd has style = "width":50% and "value-now"= 50 set to same value. How are they connected, why do they have to be the same?

If I delete all other aria attributes and only leave "style=width"=50% , it still shows 50%. It seems other attrs - aria-min, aria-max, value-now are irrelevant.

[image: ddd]

Comment: All ARIA attributes are a standard for screen readers. Using ARIA attributes will make your site more accessible.

Comment: @Klooven, so the actual progress bar is shown with style=width..

Comment: Yes, that's how it works.

Answer (score 5):

The ARIA attributes are there for accessibility reasons. Meaning: It allows people with low or no vision proper access to your web content via their screen readers.

A screen reader will read out the values to them so they can make sense of your web content.

It is highly recommended to keep your web content as accessible (for screen reader devices) as possible.

Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA

Comment: though it does not clearly answer my question, thx for clarifying!

Comment: What do you mean by "does not clearly answer my question"? The answer is: You could leave those ARIA attributes out. They aren't needed to make the progress bar work. But if you leave them out, people with screen readers won't be able to make sense of your web content.